# Palindrome question using filter and lambda

Tags: python, lambda, filter, palindrome

I don't understand why function `plnd` returns correct results but `plnd_v` does not.

Maybe someone here can explain what is happening behind the scenes.
The sentence checked is:

```
sen = "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"
```

and it is a palindrome.

```
def plnd(a):
    filtered_rev = filter(lambda x: x.isalnum(),sen)
    lower_rev = map(lambda x: x.lower(), filtered_rev)

    rev = ''.join(lower_rev)[::-1]
    print(len(rev))

    filtered = filter(lambda x: x.isalnum(),sen)
    lower = map(lambda x: x.lower(), filtered)

    reg = ''.join(lower)
    print(len(reg))

    if rev == reg:
        print(f"'{sen}' is a Palindrome! ")
    else:
        print("Not a palindrome")
```

```
def plnd_v(a):
    filtered = filter(lambda x: x.isalnum(),sen)
    lower = map(lambda x: x.lower(), filtered)

    rev = ''.join(lower)[::-1]

    reg = ''.join(lower)

    if rev == reg:
        print(f"'{sen}' is a Palindrome! ")
    else:
        print("Not a palindrome")
```

Comment: After `rev = ''.join(lower)[::-1]`, `lower` is "empty". That's why a new `lower` has to be created in the first function to make it work.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks! That was my suspicion!